# Hadoop cdh4: reducers finish before mappers are complete

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I am seeing a weird behavior with hadoop cdh4. Some of the reducers are complete before all mappers are complete. I thought all all reducers (call to reduce()) have to wait till mappers are complete. Is this an hadoop bug? Is their some scenario the job could end up in this state? What am I missing here?

[image: Reducers finish before mappers]

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong.My reducers too run along with my mappers (not along as such. But then they seem to progress as and when they recieve necessary data from mappers). Also your no of reducers task is almost half that of no of mappers. So your reducer 97% isnt exactly the same as mapper 97%. Maybe the mapper 3% left produces is enough data for  reducer with 3% left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you see weird behavior with the Hadoop UI when the Job tends to fail. I think you are seeing this because you have a task failure or may be more, that's some failed to get reflected in the UI. May be due to some delay in network communication between tasktrackers and jobtacker or internal computation (I'm not very sure). This isn't pretty well documented.

I'm afraid I cannot help you more than that. You might want to look for any bugs for Hadoop WebUI. I'll get back to you if I find any.

Comment: I expect all the reducers to be in running state and none of them should be in completed state. But as you can see most of the reducers are already finished.

Comment: I'm sorry I inferred your question wrong the last time I answered. Please accept my apology. My head works slow sometimes.